# Одновременная проверка EditText и CheckBox (Java Android)

Tags: java, android, checkbox, edittext

В приложении есть страница регистрации со стандартными полями: емаил, пароль, подтверждение пароля, фамилия, имя. После заполнения полей нужно поставить галочку, чтобы подтвердить своё согласие на обработку данных. Чтобы кнопка "Зарегистрироваться" стала доступной для нажатия, должны быть выполнены следующие условия:

1. Все поля EditText не пустые;
2. Емаил корректный;
3. Два поля с паролями совпадают;
4. Стоит галочка, подтверждающая согласие пользователя на обработку данных.

Первые 3 условия заложены с помощью TextWatcher, всё прекрасно работает:

```
        final TextWatcher watcher = new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if ((!PassReg.getText().toString().equals(PassRegConfirm.getText().toString()))
                        && PassReg.getText().toString().length() != 0
                        && PassRegConfirm.getText().toString().length() != 0) {
                    TextPassWarnReg.setText("Пароли не совпадают");
                } else {
                    TextPassWarnReg.setText("");
                }
        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (!checkEmailValidReg || EmailReg.getText().toString().length() == 0 ||
                    PassReg.getText().toString().length() == 0 || PassRegConfirm.getText().toString().length() == 0 ||
                    !PassReg.getText().toString().equals(PassRegConfirm.getText().toString()) ||
                    LastnameReg.getText().toString().length() == 0 || NameReg.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
                RegBut.setEnabled(false);
                RegBut.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.butradnotenabled);
            } else {
                RegBut.setEnabled(true);
                RegBut.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.butradenabled);
            }
        }
    };
```

Если отдельно поставить слушатель на CheckBox, тоже работает. А вот сделать так, чтобы проверялись одновременно и EditText и CheckBox не получается. Нужно учесть, что пользователь может вернуться к каким-то полям и исправить их, стереть содержимое или же снять галочку с чекбокса, то есть слушать нужно постоянно и то и другое и объединять результат. Были попытки создать две логические переменные и засунуть одну в проверку EditText полей и присваивать значение True, если всё хорошо, а вторую в CheckBox, но как эти переменные потом обрабатывать непонятно, тут получается тоже нужен слушатель для этих переменных, который непонятно как сделать.
Подскажите, как решается такая задача, вроде она вполне стандартная, но информацию найти не удалось.

Comment: Если в проекте используется Rx, то можно было бы через него сделать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создайте некую сущность типа

```
class Checker {

    private boolean isChecked;
    private boolean isTextEntered;

    // setters and getters

    public boolean isValidationSuccess() {
        return isChecked && isTextEntered;
    }
}
```

собственно создайте экземпляр этого объекта и в каждом отдельном листенере задавайте флаги по отдельности, и после срабатывания любого листенера вызывайте метод `isValidationSuccess()` чтоб проверить разблокировать ли кнопку.

Comment: Получилось, спасибо!